# Access and read a file inside Android project

Tags: android, properties, project, layer

I'm working on an Android project with multiple layers such as core,business,gui etc.

I wanna read an Application.properties file in core layer for example but when I use standart java file reading methods I access phone directories.

How can I load such a properties file that resides under com.xxx.properties package in my core layer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example have access to a file you previsously placed in the assets folder.

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(name_of_file);
```

and you can use:

```
myInput.read();
```

Comment: Yes i tried that.Putting it in assets folder and accessing.It's works fine.But I will keep the file inside a source package as i told.I try to find the way to load that props file while it is inside a source package.